# Signaling multiple threads to start working at the same time

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

I have a server that accepts data from client. The data come in big chunks in irregular intervals. I have a one thread that keeps the connection open, reads data from buffer and puts them to queue. I have another thread that picks up request, prepares them for calculation then it should hand them of to worker threads.

I have 4 worker threads. This is a producer-consumer scenario. I have a logic for each thread worked out, but I need to figure out how to do this scenario:

1) producer picks up and prepares a request

2) producer signals worker threads to run and goes to sleep

3) after all worker threads are done, signal producer to wake up and process result, workers go to sleep

4) repeat

How to signal all workers to wake up? I can't use semaphore, because I need to have all 4 workers run at the same time. I also don't want to delete the workers after they are done and create new ones for each request (I want to reuse threads).

Each worker has `while(true)` loop. I want to stop each thread at the beginning of the loop, then wake them up in producer, wait until they are all done and at the end of the while loop signal producer.

Obviously no busy waiting, that is just bad.

Comment: How do you do it now? Show your code.

Comment: Use semaphores, it's the easier way to do it... show us yours and I will show you mine

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with event objects. In Windows, you'd use an [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Basically, the event is initially unsignaled and all threads wait on it. When the producer wants the threads to start, it signals the event. All threads that are waiting on it are released.

Of course, you'll probably want a stop event, too, so that after the threads signal the producer they stop. It looks something like this.

```
start_event = new event
stop_event = new event
```

on the producer side:

```
do forever
    get data

    start_event.signal
    // wait for all threads to signal that they're done

    // clear the start event so that threads won't go past it
    start_event.clear

    // allow threads to go back to waiting for new data
    stop_event.signal

    // wait for all threads to signal that they're ready
    // and then reset the stop event
    stop_event.clear
```

On the consumer side:

```
do forever
    wait for start event
    process data
    signal producer
    // wait here for producer to release
    wait for stop event
    // signal producer that thread cleared the stop event
```

Some threading libraries (like the .NET CLR) have synchronization objects like countdown event or barrier that simplify this quite a bit, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: The pthreads equivalent here would be the condition variable. Although for this particular question, the less general pthreads barrier might be a better fit.